# Unity Wegl stuck at 90% in GitHub page but works perfectly fine locally

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

So I am new to Unity and I just started learning how to use unity webgl with GitHub pages and I am having problems viewing my game as a GitHub page. It works perfectly fine locally, but it remains at 90% while loading as a GitHub page. I followed all the steps to set up the GitHub repo and I change the compression format to disable as I saw this as answer to another question. What could it be? so weird it works on local host but remains stuck on GitHub.

This is my repo https://github.com/MelisaBogdan/IntroGame and I am trying to access the game from this https://melisabogdan.github.io/IntroGame/build/build3/index.html

Any ideas? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have any code stripping enabled? Assuming you are referencing [`this thread`](https://forum.unity.com/threads/uncaught-referenceerror-unityframework-is-not-defined-at-htmlscriptelement-script-onload-webgl.803967/page-2). Another tip is to `Enable decompression fallback` as well as `Compression Format` as enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In case its of any help, you can debug on the browser:

```
function d() {
    return new Promise(function(e, t) {
        var r = document.createElement("script");
        r.src = l.frameworkUrl,
        r.onload = function() {
            var t = unityFramework; //error is here
            unityFramework = null,
            r.onload = null,
            e(t)
        }
        ,
        document.body.appendChild(r),
        l.deinitializers.push(function() {
            document.body.removeChild(r)
        })
    }
    )
}
```

Throws the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: unityFramework is not defined at HTMLScriptElement.r.onload`

Comment: I also got the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` in reference to `build3.framework.js.br:1 ` if that adds any more detail.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to solve it.. I saw the errors